# Button background based on the content Textblock text

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I am trying to set `Button` background color based on the `TextBlock` `Text`. `TextBlock` is part of the `Button`'s `Content` and has been binded to viewmodel property.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
      <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="Title" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
      </Button.Content>
</Button>

<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                     <Border Name="bd">
                          <ContentPresenter />
                     </Border>
                     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                         //HOW TO HERE...
                         <Trigger Property="Text" Value="SomeText 1">
                              <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="#b5e61d"/>  
                         </Trigger>
                         <Trigger Property="Text" Value="SomeText 2">
                              <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="#99d9ea"/>  
                         </Trigger>
                     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>  
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
 </Style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to include title TextBlock in Button's template and then create triggers based on `Content` value:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="bd">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Content" Value="SomeText 1">
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="#b5e61d"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Content" Value="SomeText 2">
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="#99d9ea"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Content="{Binding SomeValue}" />
```